# Avoid AmbiguousMethod exception, but GetMethod returns null even with parameter list added

Tags: c#, reflection

This question has been asked before but I can't figure it out for my case.

I get null from the following code:

```
typeof(SettingsController)
    .GetMethod("GetById", new[] { typeof(Guid?), typeof(IValidator<>), typeof(HttpStatusCode) });
```

I need to pass the parameter list because I've got two methods with the same name in the **base** class of SettingsController:

```
public T GetById<T>(Guid? id, IValidator<T> validator, HttpStatusCode statusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK)

public T GetById<T>(Guid? id, string route, IValidator<T> validator, HttpStatusCode statusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK)
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I found, hope it'll help you to dig further:

```
var unspecificMethodType = typeof(Program).GetMethod("GetById", new[] { typeof(Guid?), typeof(IValidator<>), typeof(HttpStatusCode) });
unspecificMethodType.Dump(); // null

var method = typeof(Program).GetMethods()
                            .Where(m => m.Name == "GetById")
                            .First();
var methodGenericType = method.GetGenericArguments()[0];
methodGenericType.Dump(); // T

var specificMethodType = typeof(Program).GetMethod("GetById", new[] { typeof(Guid?), typeof(IValidator<>).MakeGenericType(methodGenericType), typeof(HttpStatusCode) });
specificMethodType.Dump(); // GetById (Guid? id, IValidator<T> validator, HttpStatusCode statusCode
```

From what I can see the problem can be highlighted by this test:

```
var paramType = method.GetParameters()[1].ParameterType;
paramType.Dump(); // Program+IValidator`1[T]
(paramType == typeof(IValidator<>)).Dump(); // false
```

Comment: Yup, I'm using GetMethods() with Linq as a workaround. Thank for your insight.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way to obtain a specific `MethodInfo` for a single method, when there are multiple overloads with different constraints, is by creating a new delegate with a matching signature;

```cs
var method = new Func<Guid?, IValidator<object>, HttpStatusCode,object>(((SettingsController)null).GetById).Method;
```

This is particularly useful when there are many similar methods. For example, the dotnet framework uses [this technique](https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System.Core/System/Linq/IQueryable.cs#L43) to distinguish between the many similar overloads of `IQueryable`.